# SubType reference in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

Please help, the question is at the bottom.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NameType AS OBJECT 
(firstName VARCHAR(20), middleName VARCHAR(20), lastName VARCHAR(20))
INSTANTIABLE
FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ServicerType AS OBJECT 
(servicerID INTEGER, servicerType VARCHAR(10))
INSTANTIABLE
FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PersonType AS OBJECT 
(personID INTEGER, name NameType, gender CHAR(1))
INSTANTIABLE
NOT FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EmployeeType UNDER PersonType 
(servicerRef REF ServicerType)
NOT INSTANTIABLE
NOT FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE FullTimeEmployeeType UNDER EmployeeType 
(yearlySalary NUMBER(19,4))
INSTANTIABLE
FINAL;

CREATE TABLE Servicer OF ServicerType;
CREATE TABLE Person OF PersonType;

INSERT ALL
INTO Servicer values (ServicerType(100, 'Company')
SELECT * FROM dual

INSERT ALL
INTO Person VALUES (FullTimeEmployeeType(200, 
    NameType('Bob', 'T', 'Builder'), 'M', 
    (select ref(s) from servicer s where servicerid = 100), 56700))
SELECT * FROM dual
```

Now I want to run this query:

```
select p.gender, p.name.firstName, p.name.lastName, p.yearlySalary from person p
```

I got an error. I know that yearlySalary is in FullTimeEmployee which is a subtype of person, but I just don't know how to reference it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [TREAT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/functions183.htm) function

```
select p.gender, p.name.firstName, p.name.lastName,
        treat(value(p) as FullTimeEmployeeType).yearlySalary
from person p
/
```